# How to reuse Java methods with very nearly identical implementations using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a series of Java methods which all look the same except for a different class like `Class1Number`, `Class2Number`, `Class3Number`, etc. as implemented below. Is there any way to write a single method which takes the class as a parameter?

```
Set<String> trimClass1NumberList(Set<String> criteria){
    Set<String> validData = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Class1Number> numberList = criteria.stream().map(String::trim).map(Class1Number::valueOf)
        .filter(Class1Number::isWellformed).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    for (Class1Number num : numberList) {
        // Do somehing with validData
    }
    return validData;
}

Set<String> trimClass2NumberList(Set<String> criteria){
    Set<String> validData = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Class2Number> numberList = criteria.stream().map(String::trim).map(Class2Number::valueOf)
        .filter(Class2Number::isWellformed).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    for (Class2Number num : numberList) {
        // Do somehing with validData
    }
    return validData;
}
```

Comment: Looks like all your classes are supposed to implement a common interface, and then you can program to that interface.

Comment: I think both answers are valid.  If you weren't calling two different methods on your class, I'd say that the more complete functional answer would be perfect.  But since you are having to pass in two methods on the same object, it might be cleaner to abstract an interface from all of your classes and pass that as a single parameter so you could make method calls on it from within trimNumberList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```java
<T> Set<String> trimNumberList(Set<String> criteria, Function<String, T> valueOf, Predicate<T> isWellFormed){
    Set<String> validData = new HashSet<>();
    Set<T> numberList = criteria.stream().map(String::trim).map(valueOf)
            .filter(isWellFormed).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    for (T num : numberList) {
        // Do somehing with validData
    }
    return validData;
}
```

then call it like

```
trimNumberList(criteria, Class1Number::valueOf, Class1Number::isWellFormed);
trimNumberList(criteria, Class2Number::valueOf, Class2Number::isWellFormed);
```

Doing anything special with your instances in the for loop will require a common base type, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a common abstract superclass or a common interface for Class1Number, Class2Number, Class3Number and use that instead of the real subclasses in your method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your class have the same sort of behaviour.

If also the methods that you're using on them are the same my advice is to use Java Inheritance as I'll describe below

```
class Super {
   .....
   .....
}
class Sub extends Super {
   .....
   .....
}
```

in your case will be

```
class Class0Number {

theMethodYouUse(){
.....
};

}

class Class1Number extends Class0Number {

// and maybe for different behaviour inside the for each block you can override the method and use always the same by overriding it

@Override
theMehodYouUse(){
......
};

}
```